# Integer field name changes automatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Last week I had imported some shapefiles into file geodatabase. It makes sense but when I checked table of the outputs I had found that some integer field names had been changed to other names. For example original name is 2010 changed to F1.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Field Names [Can't start with a number](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23087)
 • Eliminate any characters that are not alphanumeric character or an underscore.
• Do not start field or table names with an underscore or a number.
• It is necessary to edit the field names in delimited text files to remove unsupported characters before using them.